# Pass two different types of object as one function variable

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I want to create a function that takes two different subclasses of UIViewController. One is a UITableViewController, and one is a UIViewController (both inherit from UIViewController). In my function, I want to then check which type the ViewControllers are, in order to access their properties in my function. How can I do this, if it is possible? I have tired the following:

```
internal func myFunction(var controller: UIViewController) {

        if controller is MyController {
            controller = controller as! MyController
        }
        // Get errors saying my MyController properties are not available. Type of UIViewController has no member.
}
```

Comment: If both inherit from UIViewController you should receive a UIViewController as the parameter

Comment: What type is MenuController and MyController? Any of those is parent of the other?

Comment: Shoot, I am sorry, another typo. I have cleaned up my question. I am on mobile, and I am missing these things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you right, you would like to know which type is your parameter. If so, use this kind of method:

```
internal func myFunction(controller: UIViewController) {

    if let menu = controller as? MenuController {
        //menu is you MenuCOntroller
    } else if let table = controller as? UITableViewController {
        //table is your UITableViewController
    }

}
```